# MultiValueDictKeyError when passing empty file

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, web

In my website uploading picture is not compulsory, Therefore when left empty I get
MultiValueDictKeyError

But if i pass an image is dont get an error.
Am I missing some thing?? Thanks in advance....

views.py

```
 if request.method == "POST":
        FirstName = request.POST['FirstName']
        LastName = request.POST['LastName']
        image = request.FILES['image'] #This one 
        age = request.POST['age']
        gender = request.POST['gender']
        address = request.POST['address']
        PhoneNumber = request.POST['PhoneNumber']
        EmailAddress = request.POST['EmailAddress']
        Password = request.POST['Password']
        RepeatPassword = request.POST['RepeatPassword']
        BloodGroup = request.POST['BloodGroup']

        try:
            if Password == RepeatPassword:
                Patient.objects.create(FirstName=FirstName, LastName=LastName, image=image, age=age, gender=gender,
                                       address=address, PhoneNumber=PhoneNumber, EmailAddress=EmailAddress, BloodGroup=BloodGroup)
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.success(
                    request, ("Passwords do not match. Please try again"))
        except Exception as e:
            messages.success(
                request, ("This email already exists. Try again with another email or recover your account"))
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-div one">
        <div class="i">
            <ion-icon name="image-sharp"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="div">
            <h5>Photo</h5>
            <input type="file" class="input" name="image">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.get()` instead, i.e:

```py
image = request.FILES.get('image')
```

It will resolve to `None` if it can't find it. You can set the default to something else with:

```py
image = request.FILES.get('image', "New default that isn't None")
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp